# Spock throw exception test

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I test Java code with Spock. I test this code:

```
 try {
    Set<String> availableActions = getSthAction()
    List<String> goodActions = getGoodAction()
    if (!CollectionUtils.containsAny(availableActions ,goodActions )){
       throw new CustomException();
    }
} catch (AnotherCustomExceptio e) {
     throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
}
```

I wrote test:

```
def "some test"() {
    given:
    bean.methodName(_) >> {throw new AnotherCustomExceptio ("Sth wrong")}
    def order = new Order();
    when:
    validator.validate(order )
    then:
    final CustomException exception = thrown()
}
```

And it fails because `AnotherCustomExceptio` is thrown. But in the `try{}catch` block I catch this exception and throw a `CustomException` so I expected that my method will throw `CustomException` and not `AnotherCustomExceptio`. How do I test it?

Comment: Can you expand the context of the Java Code, showing `bean` and `validator`, `Order`?

Comment: It's not clear how the production code and test code shown above fit together. (E.g. there is no call to `bean#methodName` in the production code.) Most likely, the exception isn't thrown from the try-block shown above. You should be able to verify this in the debugger.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: I do not know :) I wrote this question year ago :) But, what about move "    bean.methodName(_) >> {throw new AnotherCustomExceptio ("Sth wrong")}" to "when" section. Could you try?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I believe your `then` block needs to be fixed. Try the following syntax:

```
then:
thrown CustomException
```

Answer (score 64):

If you would like to evaluate for instance the message on the thrown Exception, you could do something like:

```
then:
def e = thrown(CustomException)
e.message == "Some Message"
```

Answer (score 12):

There could be multiple ways to handle the exception in then:

```
thrown(CustomException)
```

or

```
thrown CustomException
```

As well we can check if no Exception is thrown in the Test case -

```
then:

noExceptionThrown()
```

Comment: Both the "doThrow" and "when" statements seem to be from Mockito.  Will Mockito statements work with a Spock mock, or does the mock object have to be created through Mockito?

Comment: @SteveGelman by "when", are you referring to the [Spock `when:` block label](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_when_and_then_blocks)?